# how to write a filter in react js with checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a cont that later on will be replaced with a api but now it looks like this which is similar to the later api :

```
const foo = {
 {'id':1,
 'price':200,
 'type':1,},
  {'id':2,
 'price':200,
 'type':2,},
};
```

and i am using a simple matterial ui checkbox :

```
render() {
const { classes } = this.props;

return (
  <FormGroup row>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.checkedA}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedA')}
          value="checkedA"
        />
      }
      label="type A"
    />
```

now i want a simple filter system for when this checkbox in checked just bring the first item which type is 1 or the price is 200 for example

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get your question. First of all, you have an error in your `foo` object. Is it supposed to be an array of objects? Now, if that's an array, you can hook into the `handleChange` function and use the `filter` function on the `foo` array to get only the items you need.

Comment: @Sergiu yes you write my mistake sorry i want to filter data by checkbox i mean when the user check the Type A check box all data of type a shows to him or her can you do any guide to write it for this simple example ?

Comment: you just need to filter the data in the `render` method when the checkbox is checked, if it's not the case you just need to render all the data without any filter

Comment: @OlivierBoissé exacly i want that but i dont know how to do taht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you need to filter your data based on what checkbox is checked. If your data is an array you can filter it like this:

```
const foo = [
 { 'id': 1, 'price': 200, 'type': 1 },
 { 'id': 2, 'price': 200, 'type': 2 }
];

const filteredData = foo.filter(item => item.type === selectedType);
```

where `selectedType` is your checked checkbox's value.

I hope this helps.